# How to implement change log with JPA?

Tags: jpa, changelog

I have an entity class manged by with JPA, and I have one entity that needs to be loged changes in its property. Does JPA provides any ways to handle this kind of requirement ?

Comment: Please check this link http://www.blogeek.com.ar/2012/12/15/how-to-passively-log-changes-to-your-jpa-model-add-modify-and-delete-with-example/ That's exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See,

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Advanced_Topics#History

and,

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Auditing_and_Security

If you are using EclipseLink it include historical support.  You can enable a class to have all of its changes tracked in a separate historical table.

Comment: it said in the link that "JPA does not define any specific history support.", but can I implement it my own, or there is no way to done this ?

Answer (score 4):

If you use Hibernate as JPA provider then have a look at [Hibernate-Envers](http://docs.jboss.org/envers/docs/index.html).

If you use Spring, then have at [Hades](http://redmine.synyx.org/projects/show/hades), or its successor [Spring-Data-JPA](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/1.0.0.M2/reference/html/).

Both (Envers and Hades/Spring-Data-JPA) provide auditing functionality. Hibernate Envers is very powerful and Hades/Spring-Data-JPA is more light ([Hades reference, chapter auditing](http://hades.synyx.org/static/2.x/site/org.synyx.hades/reference/htmlsingle/index.html#auditable-entities)).

If you do not want/can use any of them, then may you have to hook in the entity lifecycle. with [@PostUpdate](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/PostUpdate.html) and co.

Comment: My project was written with pure JPA without those hibernate or spring guess I have to go for @postUpdate. Do you have any resource for that ?

Comment: found example here http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Advanced_Topics#Example_of_Entity_event_annotations, but it seem that I can't use entitymanager in the callback, can I ?

Comment: For those who would like to intgrate Hibernate-Envers with Spring-Data-JPA, watch this ticket https://jira.springsource.org/browse/DATAJPA-7